# JQuery XDSoft datetimepicker plugin keyboard accebility issue (I am not able to select date with keyboard)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I can select date and time with mouse but my requirement is that select date and time with keyboard(key like tab, arrow).

Please help me solve the issue.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#filter-date').datetimepicker();

    $('#filter-date').keydown(function(e) {
      const input = $(this);
      const currentValue = input.val();
      const newDate = new Date(currentValue);

      if (e.keyCode === 37) { // Left Arrow
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 1);
      } else if (e.keyCode === 39) { // Right Arrow
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
      }

      // Update the input field with the new date value
      input.val(newDate.toISOString());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: No need to wrap ready in a ready

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research .  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output by clicking [edit] and use the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda better now than previous response! You can solve your problem doing it like this:

Also appear that `datetimepicker` doesn't support keyboard navigation, so I used jQuery UI Datepicker approach to solve it.

```js
    $(function() {
      $('#filter-date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
      });

      $('#filter-date').keydown(function(e) {
        const input = $(this);
        const currentDate = new Date(input.datepicker('getDate'));

        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
          currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);
          input.datepicker('setDate', currentDate);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
          currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
          input.datepicker('setDate', currentDate);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
          currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 7);
          input.datepicker('setDate', currentDate);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
          currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 7);
          input.datepicker('setDate', currentDate);
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="filter-date" value="2023-01-01">
</body>
```

Comment: You could post the example here using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: @mplungjan i'll have it present nex time, i've used it before but, i've already did the code in fiddle so i just linked it, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, corrected. :(

Comment: The native datepicker can navigate with arrows too. But there is no time in the ui datepicker